# Doctrine Entity Relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Am having a bit of a challenge creating entity relationship between a product its Category and associated color(s) with the following Entities (I omitted the getters and setters though):

```
#Product
    /**
    * Product
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="product")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
    */
    class Product
    {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="integer")
     *
     * Many Products have one category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * Many Products have one color
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Color", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="color", type="integer")
     */
    private $color;
    }

#Category
    /**
    * Category
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="category")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
    */
    class Category
    {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=170, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="desc", type="string", length=170, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * One Category has many products assigned to it
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $products;

    /**
    * Class Constructor
    *
    * @param None
    * @return void
    **/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    }

#Color
    class Color{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="color", type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $hexcode;

    /**
     * One Color has many products assigned to it
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="color", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $products;

    /** 
    * Class Constructor
    *
    * @param none
    * @return void
    **/
    public function _construct(){
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();   
    }
    }
```

When I run:

```
* php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate:
```

I get the error messages:

```
* The association AppBundle\Entity\Category#products refers to the owning 
side field AppBundle\Entity\Product#category which is not defined as 
association, but as field.

* The association AppBundle\Entity\Category#products refers to the owning 
side field AppBundle\Entity\Product#category which does not exist.
```

and:

```
* The association AppBundle\Entity\Color#products refers to the owning side 
field AppBundle\Entity\Product#color which is not defined as association, 
but as field.
* The association AppBundle\Entity\Color#products refers to the owning side 
field AppBundle\Entity\Product#color which does not exist.
```

I noticed that whenever I comment out the lines:

```
** @ORM\Column(name="category", type="integer")
** @ORM\Column(name="color", type="integer")
```

The above errors vanish but I get a new message and error saying:

```
** [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
** [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current 
 mapping file.
```

What could i be doing wrong, am new to the doctrine concept, and i have followed the documentations. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: the second message only say that you need to execute the schema update in order to sync the table structure

Comment: Remove `@ORM\Column` definition from associations

Comment: Did you try to change @ORM\Column to @ORM\JoinColumn ?

Comment: @Albeis like i said earlier, i followed the documentation and did exactly as it says

Comment: @MaxP. That seem to have done the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Doctrine ORM the relations are not Integers but Entity objects.

Remove The `@ORM\Column` annotations from all fields with relations (in each entity).

Then update your database schema in development environment with:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Then generate a doctrine migration file to execute on your production server

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate
```

Update the generetad migration file to your needs

And execute him by this way

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute timestampOfTheMigrateFile
```